# What's "node" doing in this snippet of SML?

Tags: types, compiler-errors, sml, signature, smlnj

I'm working on a project that has a lot code that looks like this:

```
structure MyStruct = struct
datatype node
  = A of Foo.t
  | B

type t = node Wrap.t

fun layout myNode =
  case node myNode of
    A foo => Foo.bar foo 
  | B => "void"
end
```

`Wrap` is defined elsewhere, but the main point is that it has one parametrized type, `t`.

What is `node` doing in the line `case node myNode of`? It's not a type constructor, since `t` isn't a type, and changing it to `case (node myNode)` throws an error message for that reason. Additionally, if I write functions that look like this:

```
fun layout node myNode = ...
```

I get a type error because it doesn't have the type `MyStruct.t -> Layout.t` but rather `'a -> MyStruct.node -> Layout.t`. If I do the same thing inside of a case statement, however, it's fine.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some function named `node` defined in the program, whose type is `u -> node`, for some `u`. That function is applied here. From that, the `layout` function then is simply inferred to have type `u -> string`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. It turns out that this project is organized such that every one of these structures has a `datatype node` that then gets shadowed by a function `node` with type `'a Wrap.t -> 'a` because of an `open` declaration that I didn't include. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickCollins, there is no shadowing, actually, since type and value identifiers live in different namespaces (as do modules and sigantures). For example, it's fine to write s.th like `fun f (time : time) = ...` in ML.

Comment: Ah, okay, I suppose that makes more sense. I was extremely confused by this pattern -- I guess it is less opaque to someone with a better grasp of the language.